# Finding Duplicate files in a specific directory and eliminating them - Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, duplicates

How could we find duplicated files in a certain folder and its sub-folders with also the possibility to eliminate them at the user's will?

Well, this is a way i found that this could be possible. The file and directory are not variable, are fixed and the user would have to edit the code in the program each time it wanted another file and/or another directory to work with.

I recently asked a question about my program and as promissed i would share it when it would be completed.

The program finds the duplicates in a folder and sub-folders of the directory chosen, lists them by order from ancient to the most recent one and it gives the user the choice to eliminate the files, file by file, at the user's will (telling the user which file is up to being deleted/eliminated).

Im very new to this kind of programming so if it is not the prettiest of programs im sorry, but it works and i haven't found something like this anywhere. I hope this helps someone!

```
    @echo off
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    
    set "source_folder=C:\Desktop\Batch testes\Teste 1\Giorgio.docx"
    
    echo Welcome to this Practice/Test Program
    echo This program has the obective of finding duplicated files. 
    pause
    echo The user will have the chance to eliminate these files if he wishes
    echo There will be the identification of the oldest and the newest file
    pause
    
    echo Let us start...
    pause
    
              
    :aPrompt
    cls
    echo ========================================
    echo What do you wish to do?
    echo 1.Show only the duplicated files. (Clique '1')
    echo 2.Show the duplicated files and eliminate them.  (Clique '2')
    echo 3.Exit the program (Clique '3')
    
    
    
    choice /n /c:123 /M "Escolha uma opcao "%1
    goto Alfa-%errorlevel%
    
    
    :Alfa-1 A1
    
       
       echo Showing the files being analysed
    
       forfiles /P "C:\Desktop\Batch testes\Teste 1" /M Giorgio.docx /S /C "cmd /c echo @file"
    
       echo Showing the paths of the files being analysed
       
       forfiles /P "C:\Desktop\Batch testes\Teste 1"  /M Giorgio.docx /S /C "cmd /c echo @relpath@fname"
    
       pause
       echo ===============================================================================
       echo.         
       echo The files are set by order from the oldest (on top) to the most recent (on the bottom)         
   echo.
   (for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /t:w /s /b "C:\Desktop\Batch testes\Teste 1\*Giorgio.docx"') do @echo %%~Ta %%a) 
      
   echo.
   echo The oldest file is on top of the list. The most recent file is at the bottom of the list
       
       
    
     
      echo.
      echo=======================
      echo=======================
      pause
         
       :bPrompt
       echo Here are the duplicated files
       echo Do you wish to leave or go back? (Type '1' to end the program, '2' to return to the previous menu)
       
      
       
       choice /n /c:12 /M "Pick an option "%1
       goto Bravo-%errorlevel%
       :Bravo-1 B
          echo The program will now end
          pause
          exit
       
       :Bravo-2 B
          echo You chose to go back
          pause
          goto :aPrompt
    
    :Alfa-2 A2
    
       echo You chose to show and eliminate the duplicated files
       pause
       echo Showing the files paths
       forfiles /P "C:\Desktop\Batch testes\Teste 1"  /M Giorgio.docx /S /C "cmd /c echo @relpath@fname" 
       
       echo Files identyfied by the the program (it serves the purpose of confirming if they are the right files)
       
       forfiles /P "C:\Desktop\Batch testes\Teste 1" /M Giorgio.docx /S /C "cmd /c echo @file"
    
        echo The files are set by order from the oldest (on top) to the most recent (on the bottom)         
   echo.
   (for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /t:w /s /b "C:\Desktop\Batch testes\Teste 1\*Giorgio.docx"') do @echo %%~Ta %%a) 
      
   echo.
   echo The oldest file is on top of the list. The most recent file is at the bottom of the list
       
       echo You sure you want to delete the files? (Type '1' to eliminate them, '2' to not eliminate)
       
       :cPrompt
       choice /n /c:12 /M "Pick an option "%1
       goto Charlie-%errorlevel%
       :Charlie-1 C1
       
           echo You chose to delete the files
           
           
           echo The files will be deleted according to your decision
           echo For each file it will be asked if you wish to delete it
           pause
           del /p /s "C:\Desktop\Batch testes\Teste 1"\*Giorgio.docx 
           echo The files have been deleted at your choice
           pause
           :dPrompt
           echo Do you wish to exit the program or go back? (Type '1' to end the program, type '2' to go back to the main menu)
           
           choice /n /c:12 /M "Pick an option "%1
           goto Delta-%errorlevel%
           :Delta-1 D1
           
           
               echo You chose to leave. The program will shut down
               pause
               exit
           
           :Delta-2 D2
          
           
               echo You chose to go back to the main menu
               pause
               goto :aPrompt
       
       :Charlie-2 C2
       
           :ePrompt
           echo You chose not to delete the files.
           echo Do you wish to go back to the main menu or to leave? (Type '1' to go back to the main menu, '2' to leave the program)
           
           
           choice /n /c:12 /M "Pick an option "%1
           goto Evo-%errorlevel%
           :Evo-1 E1
           
               echo You chose to go back to the main menu
               pause
               goto :aPrompt
           
           :Evo-2 E2
              echo You chose to exit the program. The program will shut down now
              pause
              exit
           
           
    :Alfa-3 A3
    
        echo The program will shut down then
        pause
        exit
```

If by any case something is failing/giving an error, tell me and i'll fix it because i may have copied something wrong by mistake (like a typo or a missing "(", something).
( I don't know how i could share my program without using the "ask a question" function, im sorry if i broke any rules of this website)

Special thanks to Stephan that helped me previously and without him i couldn't complete the part where i set the oldest and recent file!

Comment: Edit your question to show only the question and then post the answer with the solution. Don't post the answer as part of the quesion. Other than that, this can be simplified quite a lot, but there are some considerationa. What deternines a duplicate? Filename yes, but how do you decide which file has the wanted content to keep? Once you can describe that, it is an easy fix.

Comment: Ah! Adding a question for e.g "How could we find duplicated files and have the possibility to eliminate them?" like this?
Well, which file is to be kept depends on the user. The original file would be the oldest (which the program shows) and the user perhaps would want that to be saved. The most recent would probably be the updated one from all. But the program shows the path to each file and the user could then search for each file if he wants and see which ones would like to keep